# What is the jQuery event listener equivalent of "mouseover" on a mobile device?

Tags: jquery, mobile, mouseover, addeventlistener

I built a little function in jQuery that fires on mouseover:

```
$( 'li.class1' ).mouseover(
  function() { ... }
);
```

I am testing on my iPhone/mobile device and obviously there is no mouse movement capabilities (didn't think that far in advance).

So before I rethink and rewrite the function, I am wondering if there is an equivalent listener to use for mouseover events on a phone.

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on *touch* events

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl...reading on `touchstart` right now. Testing and it is looking like the answer.